# Background service android 8 (No JobScheduler)- Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a background service for getting the gps coordinates, from 2 seconds to 2 seconds, this works until I've tryed on Android 8.0 (Oreo). I have research for information on how to do this and I found a lot of people saying to use JobScheduler. But in this situation that I need the service too being executed from 2 seconds in 2 seconds, and long running(until user log out), I have read that the Job scheduler is not the best option.

So, in resume, has anyone got a way/clue of how I can do this to work in Android 8?

Thanks any help.

Comment: Are you foregrounding your service?

Comment: Yes, yesterday I discoverd the thing with the foreground service. Now is working, but thanks for the answer.